# how to retrieve views creation time?

Tags: mysql, view

Is it possible to know when a view has been created or updated?

If I run a query on `information_schema.tables` I get these infos only for "base table" while for view everything is equals to `null`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible because view is not a table and not contain any physical data. MySQL creates view on the current data which exist in other tables, so you only can get update time for tables.

View is only a definition, and that definition are stored in INFORMATION_SHEMA. You can only get information about definition:

```
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' AND TABLE_NAME = 'v';
```

But, you can't get update or created time.